# Simple Injector ASP.NET Singleton Dispose

Tags: asp.net, singleton, dispose, simple-injector

Simple Injector documentation is quite clear on both transient and singleton registrations, and how they will be disposed etc.  Docs indicate that singletons registered with all but the pre-constructed objects will get disposed when the container gets disposed.

My question specifically involves a singleton registration that I Need to be disposed when the ASP.NET application gets disposed (I send any remaining messages when that service is disposed). Most of my registrations are transient and get disposed when each request is disposed.  When debugging in VS/IISExpress, I don't ever see when my singletons get disposed - or when the container itself ultimately gets disposed. In my console apps & azure services I simply call container.Dispose() when I'm done. Any clues in ASP.NET for this final cleanup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For singletons to be disposed, you need to explicitly call `Container.Dispose()` when the application ends. This can be done for instance in the `Application_End` event in your Global.asax. But please be warned.

> I send any remaining messages when that service is disposed

This seems like a very bad idea, because there are many reasons why an `Application_End` event doesn't run. IIS can quite aggressively kill applications, and so will do power outages and other hardware malfunctions. If that happens, it means that you will lose any messages that are still in the local buffer.

This might not be a problem for volatile messages that are used for application heartbeats and sometimes logging, but if those messages describe important business events, you should use durable queuing or storage mechanisms.

> When debugging in VS/IISExpress, I don't ever see when my singletons get disposed

That can very well be. When debugging a web application, the web application never stops by itself. In case you stop debugging either the application is abruptly stopped without having a chance to run any finalizers and clean-up methods, or when you stop debugging, the application keeps running in the background; which still means you won't see any clean-up happening.

Comment: I totally agree with what you about the problems with such an approach, but it's better than doing nothing in most cases (i.e. just throwing away any unsent messages).  Keep in mind that even if you use redundant approaches it's not failsafe.  All I'm asking is in a hosted IIS ASP.NET environment, what's the correct way to make sure the SimpleInjector container is disposed so I at least have a chance to try and send any locally queued msgs.  Is OWIN OnAppDisposing the equivalent to Application_End?

Comment: If losing messages is a problem, I really advise you to change your design. Persist those messages in the same database  transaction as the rest of your request runs. This is a very common approach that prevents message loss. About OWIN: I'm not sure what OnAppDisposing does. You'll have to read the docs and test this.

Comment: I'll take another look at how that particular messaging is done w.r.t. the data transaction.  IIRC, the writing of message to Azure ServiceBus (what we use) had to be done outside of the ambient DB transaction scope, which kind of defeats the purpose here.  See https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/azure-service-bus/understanding-transactions-and-delivery-guarantees?version=asb_6 .  Thanks for discussion Steven!

Comment: Take a look at the [Outbox messaging pattern](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/outbox/) that NServiceBus supports. It allows storing messages in a local 'transactional' queue and send it through to the real infrastructure once it knows for sure it is safe to do so.